# Is "polluted" considered to be an adjective?

Tags: grammar

> A. Water is polluted. 
>   B. Polluted water is harmful to health.

Can we say *"polluted water"* considering *"polluted"* as an adjective

Comment: *"polluted"* in sentence #B is a clearly an adjective, but it is ambiguous in sentence #A, that means in that sentence it can be considered either as a participle form of verb or an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be a verb, past tense, as in: "A leak in the hull of a massive tanker polluted the ocean with gallons of noxious, filthy crude oil."

That being said, the two sentences you gave in your example used polluted as an adjective, you are correct to consider polluted an adjective in those examples.